# Papervision3D: Making a camera look at Plane

Tags: actionscript-3, papervision3d

I have a wall of Planes at different angles and positions. I'd like to get the camera to rotate and look straight at the focused plane. I have created a dummy Plane (lookAtMe) that tweens to the Plane I click on as follows:

```
    private function planeClicked(e:InteractiveScene3DEvent):void 
    {
        lookAtTarget.copyTransform(this);

        var time:Number = 1;
        var tweenObject:Object = {};
        tweenObject.x = lookAtTarget.x;
        tweenObject.y = lookAtTarget.y;
        tweenObject.z = lookAtTarget.z;
        tweenObject.rotationX = lookAtTarget.rotationX;
        tweenObject.rotationY = lookAtTarget.rotationY;
        tweenObject.rotationZ = lookAtTarget.rotationZ;
        tweenObject.onUpdate = onSeatTween;
        tweenObject.ease = Cubic.easeInOut;
        TweenMax.to(lookAtMe, time, tweenObject);
    }

    private function onSeatTween():void
    {
        camera.lookAt(lookAtMe);
    }
```

The camera centers on the looAtMe Plane but doesn't rotate so that the selected Plane is straight on.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand the math behind this or just are taking a guess?

Comment: Mostly guessing - I'm quite new at this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you know that your plane has a normal? It's true, it determines which side the plane is facing. A normal is a vector with a length of 1.

You can calculate the normal of a plane if you know three three-dimensional points on it. For instance: the center, the center at the top and the center at the right. Let's call the center `C`, the center at the top `M1` and the center at the right `M2`.

Here's how to calculate the normal:

```
Cross(C - M1, C - M2)
```

(If you don't know the cross product, please look it up)

This will give you the vector as defined by the arrow:

[image]

Alright, so how can we use that information? Knowing the normal of the plane and its center, we can say the following:

camera_position = plane_position + (plane_normal * distance)

This will put the camera at the correct position, some distance away from the plane.

camera_direction = plane_normal * -1

This makes the camera look at the plane.

However, I don't think ActionScript 3 defines the camera look at function with a vector, I think it uses an object. You could, for example, place a small invisible object at the center of the plane and point the camera at that. That should give you the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to work backwards - first pick a point on a plane (X,Y,Z) (by averaging?) that you want to look at. Then pick a distance D away from that point that you wish to be.

Next take the equation of a plane http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html ax+by+cz=d (different d) and from there deduce a normal vector n = (a,b,c). Normalize it and multiply by D to obtain N = (A,B,C). Now there are only two points from which you could be looking from: (X,Y,Z) +/- (A,B,C).

So, now pick whether you want to look from behind or from the front - that will affect the choice of + vs -, I just do not know which is which.

Answer (score 1):

The PV3D.org blog has a [working example](http://pv3d.org/2008/12/28/click-then-tween-camera-to-plane/) that should be exactly what you're looking for.